# Can a very recently planted B & B cypress tree be moved 2'?

Tags: trees, transplanting, conifers

The Leyland Cypress is now blocking the view intended so we'd like to have someone move it a couple of feet to the left.  Is this a cause for concern for the survival of the tree?

Comment: How recently is "recently"?

Comment: Bevy, please send a picture or two, take a picture of the entire tree and the bottom of the trunk.  Who planted this tree?  Was the burlap left in place?  It should always be removed but in construction they leave them on in case the tree needs to be moved.  How long ago is 'recently' like Niall asked?

Comment: Welcome Bevy! I have a few more questions. How old is the tree? How tall? How close would it be to other trees or plants if you move it? In order to best help you, we need as many details and pictures as possible. I invite you to check out our [help]. [ask] is a good place to start. To add information, press "edit" to open the question. If there's anything you don't understand about the site or need help with, leave a comment and someone will come along and help! Have fun!

Comment: Sue do we not have a simple question form to guide others on WHAT questions to ask?  Questions such as what is your zone?  USDA, site to show those zone areas.  How much gardening knowledge do you have on a scale from 1 to 5?  Are we discussing plants used to the indoors or the out of doors?  Under a patio, growing in a heated green house or...what soil did you put in your pots?  (leaving relevant question and answers from this site).  Do you know how to attach pictures?  No?  Here is how.  We could have a short selection of categories; ID, lawn, vegetables, insects and maybe 'I have no idea'?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by 'B & B cypress', but if you mean Cupressus leylandii (now Cuprocyparis leylandii), and by 'very recently' you mean in the last 4 - 6 weeks, then yes, it can be moved now because it won't have had time to put out many roots into the surrounding soil.

On the other hand, if 'very recently' means 6 months ago, and you're not living in the southern hemisphere of the planet, then no, you will have to wait till autumn (fall). The longer its been in situ, the higher the risk of damage to the tree.

The other thing is, moving it by only two feet seems too little - these trees get very large indeed, and two feet is likely to be neither here nor there - if its already blocking your view, it will still do so eventually, even if its moved by two feet.